# How to get the width and height of AlertDialog - Flutter Web

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-alertdialog

I want to get the exact height and width of AlertDialog in flutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand what your purpose is, rather specifying a size getting it's measurement.

**Within the context of alert dialog** you can place other components inside it, using the following. Using the following code you can get the measurements inside the UI component that you consider as context.

> alert_dialog_height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
> alert_dialog_width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

if you need to place something in the middle height of alert dialog just use

```
alert_dialog_height/2
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer about the [MediaQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67908386/19693294) doesn't work, it gives the screen size.

So, yesterday I chanced upon this, as I needed it but couldn't find a close answer, so after some experimenting, I post a roundabout method I came up with. Now, after knowing about the RenderBox widget, I came with a better method. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class testingApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AlertDialog Size'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showMyDialog(context);
          },
          child: Text('Show Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showMyDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialogStateful();
      },
    );
  }
}

class AlertDialogStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AlertDialogStatefulState createState() => _AlertDialogStatefulState();
}

class _AlertDialogStatefulState extends State<AlertDialogStateful> {
  bool isInitialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        isInitialized = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext contentContext) {
          return Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 60,
            child: (isInitialized) ?
                Text("Title: "+showAlertDialogTitleSize(contentContext)) :
                Text("Title: no data"),

          );

        },
      ),
      content: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext contentContext) {
          return Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 30,
            child: (isInitialized) ?
            Text("Data: "+showAlertDialogContentSize(contentContext)) :
            Text("no data"),

          );
        },
      ),
      actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          0, 0, 0, 0),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext contentContext) {
              return Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 90,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      (isInitialized) ?
                      Text('Action: '+showAlertDialogContentSize(contentContext)) :
                      Text('Action: no data'),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Close the dialog
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text("return"),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
              );

            },
          ),
        )

      ],
    );
  }

  String showAlertDialogContentSize(BuildContext alertDialogContext) {
    final RenderBox renderBox =
    alertDialogContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final double widthSize = renderBox.size.width;
    final double heightSize = renderBox.size.height;
    return ("width: $widthSize ; height: $heightSize");
  }
  String showAlertDialogTitleSize(BuildContext alertDialogContext) {
    final RenderBox renderBox =
    alertDialogContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final double widthSize = renderBox.size.width;
    final double heightSize = renderBox.size.height;
    return ("width: $widthSize ; height: $heightSize");
  }
  String showAlertDialogActionSize(BuildContext alertDialogContext) {
    final RenderBox renderBox =
    alertDialogContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final double widthSize = renderBox.size.width;
    final double heightSize = renderBox.size.height;
    return ("width: $widthSize ; height: $heightSize");
  }
}
```

The container is so you can play with changing its sizes.
Basically, you can use the renderBox in a stateful widget after knowing that the alertDialog widget is built, so you don't get a null error.
You use it in the title, content, and action. I put text, but you should create a variable locally global for the widget that contains width and height for title content and action and save it there.

I tried using only one set using the alertDialog inside the builder, but I got the size of the screen in return.

The answer below is one way I did it before I knew about the RenderBox widget. I leave it here because it could be useful to some..

There are lots of reasons for wanting to know the size of the alert dialog. For example, I have an app that shows information in the alert dialog and has buttons to change between data (it works like a page). Right now, I have the following problem: I can't center this button, so it always shows in the same position (indifferent to the page). Each page has a different adaptive size (depending on the screen), so I don't overflow data. The mediaQuery inside an alert dialog uses the screen or widget outside the alert dialog as context, so when the alert dialog changes width, the buttons I put are no longer centered. I can make a custom solution for one screen, but the goal of this is that I can work on every screen.

So this is how I bypass the problem: I managed to do a partly-width adaptive screen. It used all the sizes of the screen; if the screen is narrower than the maximum width I set, if it is larger than that, the width is the maximum I defined.

```
class StatusLegend extends StatelessWidget{
  const StatusLegend({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final double maxWidthSelected = 400;
  Widget buildColumn(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> rows = [
      SizedBox(width: maxWidthSelected),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // Center vertically,
        children: [

          StatusBox(color: Colors.green, label: "activo"),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Programa encendido.",
              maxLines: 2,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 8),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // Center vertically
        children: [
          StatusBox(color: Colors.grey, label: "inactivo"),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Programa apagado.",
              maxLines: 2,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 8),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // Center vertically
        children: [
          StatusBox(color: Colors.red, label: "con problemas"),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Programa no se puede ejecutar, revisalo para conocer el problema.",
              maxLines: 3,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 8),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // Center vertically
        children: [
          StatusBox(color: Colors.blue, label: "ejecución"),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              "Programa se esta ejecutando.",
              maxLines: 3,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 20),
      const Text('* El color del texto en el nombre del programa representa su estado.', textAlign: TextAlign.left,),

    ];

    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Column(
          children: rows,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double currentScreenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double padObtained = (currentScreenWidth < maxWidthSelected) ? (currentScreenWidth/2) :  (maxWidthSelected/2);
    if (padObtained > 8) padObtained -= 8;
    return AlertDialog(
      insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0,top: 0,left: 10,right: 10),
      title: const Text('Estado Programa:',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,top: 10),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0), // Set left, top, right, and bottom padding
      content:Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65, maxWidth: maxWidthSelected),
        child: Scrollbar(
          thumbVisibility: true, // Set to true to always show the scrollbar
          thickness: 8.0, // Set the thickness of the scrollbar
          radius: const Radius.circular(4.0), // Set the radius of the scrollbar thumb
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                buildColumn(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0), // Set left, top, right, and bottom padding
      actions: <Widget>[
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: padObtained),
              Text('1 / 6',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              SizedBox(
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        barrierDismissible: true,
                        barrierColor: Colors.white60, /// Aqui es donde escoges el color de fondo detras del dialogo
                        builder: (_)  => StatusLegend2()
                    );
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 1, 0), // Adjust the padding as needed
                  ),
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(), // You can use any widget inside Expanded
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the dialog when this button is pressed
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ],

    );
  }

}
```

here i defined the max width:

```
final double maxWidthSelected = 400;
```

inside the content of the alertDialog i set a sizedBox with the size of the max width to force alertDialog to occupy that size (if screen is narrower it will use all width)
:

```
SizedBox(width: maxWidthSelected)
```

In the content of alertDialog, I return a container with a constraint so I can be sure that the alertDialog doesn't surpass that size (if you put something wider in the title or action, you could get a wider alertDialog than intended):

```
constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65, maxWidth: maxWidthSelected)
```

Just as I enter the widget I defined how much I would move from border of the container (padObtained)(the 8 is so the / is in the center and not the beginning of the number):

```
double currentScreenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double padObtained = (currentScreenWidth < maxWidthSelected) ? (currentScreenWidth/2) :  (maxWidthSelected/2);
if (padObtained > 8) padObtained -= 8;
```

finally in the action i put 0 padding explicitly to start from border and a row widget where the first children is my padding.

```
SizedBox(width: padObtained),
Text('1 / 6', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
etc.
```

The final result looks good and changes well when i use my phone sideways.